# Form submit for two times with null values and given me 500 error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I created a login form which as I wanted to practice ajax from JQUERY. Unfortunately this program is given me unexpected error.

- ISSUE
  Browser is given me 500 error : NullPointerException
  So I printed username and password. Then I saw that for one button click username and password print for two times and for first time it is same values as I entered and second time username is Null password is similar to entered value.And other thing is although I commented out the Ajax part that second scenario is happening (null username and entered password printing)

JSP:

```
<form action="" style="border:1px solid #ccc" method="post">
<div class="container">
  <h2>LogIn Form</h2>
    <label><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="uName" required>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" id="login">LogIn</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

- JQUERY

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          alert("qwqw");
          $('#login').click(function(){
              $.post('userRegistrationServlet',{
                  uName : $('#uName').val(),
                  psw : $('#psw').val()},
                  function(responseText) {
                      alert(uName);
                      alert("Login Successfully..!");
                  });
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```
- Servlet

  ```
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html");  
      //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      String userName = request.getParameter("uName");
      System.out.println(userName+"uName");
      String psw = request.getParameter("psw");
      System.out.println(psw+"psw");
      RequestDispatcher rd;
      if(!userName.isEmpty()| userName != null){
      rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Header.html");
          rd.forward(request, response);
      }else{
          rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/SignUp.jsp");
          rd.forward(request, response);
      }

  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws IOException, ServletException{
      request.getRequestDispatcher("UserRegistration.jsp").forward(request,response);
  }
  ```

Please help me to solve this issue..Thank you..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather put an event handler on the "submit" event of the form, then call `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event:

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.post('userRegistrationServlet',{
            uName : $('#uName').val(),
            psw : $('#psw').val()},
            function(responseText) {
                alert(uName);
                alert("Login Successfully..!");
            });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.yes these two functions are stopped submitting two times and my another fault was caught : I changed both name and id with the value uName for username filed then it is not given me null value for username filed.

Answer (score 0):

this button type is 'submit' so when you click it your form will be submit coherently but no url path
LogIn

Comment: is that the reason for my issue?

Comment: i think so,you can try to change submit to button

Comment: yes..It is correct form  submitted only for one time by changing type submit to button